# using baseUrl affects the path to my assets

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I'm integrating an `ember-cli` app inside `my main site` which will be accessible at url `http://host/faq/....ember...routes`

So I added `baseUrl: /faq/` to my ember

**config/environment.js**

```
module.exports = function(environment) {
  var ENV = {
    modulePrefix: 'faq',
    environment: environment,
    baseURL: '/faq/',
    locationType: 'hash',
```

**The problem**: While developing in my ember-cli environment with `ember server` my assets such as (**SVG, FONTS and IMAGES**) are giving me a `NOT FOUND` now.

**For example**: `http://host/assets/images/bg.png` gives me a not found it now expects `http://host/faq/assets/images/bg.png`. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem with this project: [Ember-Material-Navigation](https://github.com/fraherm/Ember-Material-Navigation/tree/master)

I fixed this issue by defining a baseUrl variable in my main sass file and concatenating to all external urls.

```
$baseUrl: "/faq/";
@include font-face("Font Name", font-files($baseUrl + "/dir/font.ttf"));
```

However, this only works if you are using sass.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to serve assets from the root, leave base url as: `baseURL: '/'`.

Then, to customize the urls for your ember app, configure rootURL on the Router instance (app/router.js): `rootURL: '/faq/'`

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/#toc_specifying-a-root-url

Comment: Hi gdub, I just tried this but when I do, my app while using `ember server` is not accessible at http://localhost:4200/user/ it's still only accessible at http://localhost

Comment: This is deprecated in Ember 2.7

Comment: Expanding: the parameter rootURL is deprecated in Ember 2.7 http://emberjs.com/blog/2016/04/28/baseURL.html